# how to add custom column in db table when using 'into outfile' query

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this query to create CSV of my mysql DB table

```
  $path = getcwd() . '/uploads/data.csv' ;

   $sql = "select email,username from `engine4_user` LIMIT 5000 into outfile '$path' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ";
```

But now I need one extra field that is profile url .which doesn't exists on the table. So i wanna create a virtual url column using the ID of that user table. Like https://mysiteurl/profile/$user_id .

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "CONCAT" operator

```
$sql = "SELECT
        email,
        username, 
        CONCAT('https://mysiteurl/profile/',user_id) as profile_url 
        FROM `engine4_user` 
        LIMIT 5000 
        into outfile '$path' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ";
```

[See example here](http://anasthecoder.blogspot.ae/2015/09/mysql-tips-and-tricks.html)